How do I make a 3D model appear like this?
I apologize for the vague title.
Are there specific steps or modifiers to hide interior edges of a 3D model, similar to these pictures?
My goal is for the interior of the left object to look visually similar to the interior of the right object.

Object mode, front view.

Object mode, top view.

Edit mode, front view.

Edit mode, angle view.


Hello it's not clear what you show, is it a flat object?

Hello and welcome to BSE. It seems you are missing the Blender basics. There are a lot of tutorials online on the basics. And then you can try modeling something and let us know what problems you had. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rqhtw7dg6Wk

@moonboots No, its not a flat shape, it's a 3D model. The outlines of the interior edges do not show. I'm trying to replicate this 3D model.

So maybe show a less frontal view as well so that we can see its volume, it will make it more understandable

@moonboots Right, I added a view more pictures.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Create a cube, scale it, select 4 edges and bevel with one segment (CtrlB):

Select the big face and inset (i):

Pull the inset:

Mirror with a Mirror modifier, apply the modifier when you're glad:


Thanks, do you know how to replicate hiding the interior edges?

Could you please elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean

Yeah, I'm working on gem 3D models, and I found the 3D model in the pictures online. There is another picture at the bottom of the post to compare and contrast. Thanks for your time.

what difficulty do you meet exactly if you follow the steps I show?

I meet no difficulty, my original goal is to replicate the visual look (not design) of the 3D model's interior.

When you say "visual look", is this in rendered view or just in the viewport? In either case I would think you could do that by arranging the correct lighting so that the entire area is illuminated evenly because it's uneven illumination that is currently showing all the edges.
